# Record the last three hours of video with a webcam?

Tags: windows, webcam

Is there a way to use a webcam to record video to a some buffer on a computer.

For example, the buffer could store only the last three hours of video. I could then hit stop and that buffer is saved to another file that I can then play back.

This would be for Windows. I don't care about buffer size, hard drive space is cheap :P

Comment: Any specific operating system requirements?  Also, that would be a hell of a huge buffer.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect the operating system. It would be fine for any flavor of Windows XP or higher.

Comment: This sounds like something that would come up in the security field. I've never seen it for general use, but I could imagine that something similar (though with longer times) would be perfect for store security cameras, for instance.

Comment: For us humans who don't want to come up with a solution, uStream is on our side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put together a Python script that can do this. By default it will record the previous 24 hours of video. Feel free to make any modifications you want to it:

I did [a blog post describing it](http://msujaws.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/weekend-hacking-homebrew-security-camera-with-infinite-recording-length/), and made [the source code available online](http://code.google.com/p/infinite-webcam-recording/).

Comment: do you still have the source code available? Google Code was taken down. Thanks!